# Create a php function to add new node

Tags: drupal

I am new to Drupal 8 my question is:
is there a way to create a php function in **.theme** file and calling it from a twig template file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use global preprocess in .theme file.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess(array &$variables, $hook) {
  //this is a global hook, its variables are available in any template file
  $variables['test'] = 'today';
}
```

`{{ test }}` will render 'today'.

Another way is create own custom Twig functions in a custom module.
Reference -https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/271770/how-to-call-a-function-in-a-twig-file

Can call like this on twig templates `{{ getRoleValues('admin') }}`
**src/MyTwigExtension.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\MyTwigModule;

/**
 * Class DefaultService.
 *
 * @package Drupal\MyTwigModule
 */
class MyTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   * This function must return the name of the extension. It must be unique.
   */
  public function getName() {
    return 'role_values';
  }

  /**
   * In this function we can declare the extension function
   */
  public function getFunctions() {
    return array(
       new \Twig_SimpleFunction('getRoleValues',
        [$this, 'getRoleValues'],
        ['is_safe' => ['html']]
      )),
  }

  
   /**
   * Twig extension function.
   */
  public function getRoleValues($roles) {
    $value = 'not-verified';
    if ($roles == "admin") {
      $value = 'verified';
    }

    return $value;
  }

}
```

**src/MyTwigModule.services.yml**

```
services:
  MyTwigModule.twig.MyTwigExtension:
    class: Drupal\MyTwigModule\MyTwigExtension
    tags:
      - { name: twig.extension }
```